# Google maps directions using stored results

Tags: json, google-maps

I am trying to put together an app where I can query googles directions service, store the results to build up a cache then render the directions as I need them.

I can get the direction data back and store it in the database just fine, and thats all good, now when I go to render the directions over the map my javascript really lets me down. (strData) is a string containing the json formatted directions from the database.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="map.aspx.cs" Inherits="panto" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Directions Simple</title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        center: chicago
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(<%= strData %>);
}

function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            alert(response);
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<div>

</div>
<div id="map_canvas" style="top:30px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The firefox error console reports the error

```
Error: g[Xb] is not a function
Source File: http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_gb/mapfiles/api-3/5/11/main.js
Line: 109
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Yeah, I just ignored all the data that was being sent back and re-plotted using the start / end points. saved re-inventing the wheel and all that

Answer (score 9):

To render directions result from Google Web Service (vs from JavaScript API), we can use the encoded path in the result.

1. add the geometric library to decode the path:

   ```
   http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false
   ```
2. decode the path and render the polyline

   ```
   var rideCoordinates = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath(results.routes[0].overview_polyline.points);       
   var ridePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
       map:            map_object,       
       path:           rideCoordinates,
       strokeColor:    "#FF0000",
       strokeOpacity:  1.0,
       strokeWeight:   3
   });
   ```
3. set the bounds of the map

   ```
   var ne = new google.maps.LatLng(results.routes[0].bounds.northeast.lat, route.bounds.northeast.lng);
   var sw = new google.maps.LatLng(results.routes[0].bounds.southwest.lat, route.bounds.southwest.lng);
   map_object.fitBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(sw, ne));
   ```

HTH

Comment: This *totally* worked and was exactly what I needed when facing the same problem as the OP.  Thanks!

Comment: Works well after removing ".points" from ".overview_polyline.points"

Comment: Hi @kiatng, is there a way I can use `data` param? That is, can I pass custom routes (modified by users)? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you serialize the object all methods will disappear.
g[Zb] is not a function, really means cannot find the the method 'getSouthWest' on property 'bounds'.

If you would get the results and then recreate the objects like this: results.routes[0].bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBound(results.routes[0].bounds); Then atleast that first error message would be fixed...

Comment: How can we know what is g[Pb] is undefined, like g[Zb]?